# Why does mysql increase the number of connected threads?

Tags: mysql

I've been monitoring the application written in Java, and noticed something interesting about mysql. Here is the statistics it gives:

1. Number of running threads - current is 9, minimal is 2, maximum 34, avg. 7.34.
2. Now, the number of connected threads - current is 80, minimal is 19, maximum is 100, avg. is 52.

Why such a drastic difference? After restarting mysql server, number of connected threads was much lower, about 10 or so. But it keeps increasing during time. Is the sign of the connection leak somewhere in the application?

Comment: Possibly... but for clarity, please explain where/how you getting the the values for "number of running threads" and connected threads.

Comment: With the help of SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';  I use this from zabbix

Comment: Thanks.  "Number of running threads" did not sound like an "official" MySQL phrase so I wanted to check the source.  Are you familiar with the MySQL query `SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST;`?  That should give you a really good idea of what's going on.